# Change anchor link color on right click

Tags: css, internet-explorer, anchor

Using `a:active` for links in Chrome/FF works when right clicking a link and opening in a new tab to set the color of a link to show it has been clicked. In IE, however, this does not work the same. Any ideas?

Comment: I do not think there is an easy solution.. all browsers are different.

Comment: Using jQuery, I can hit all anchor links on right click, but that doesn't help:

`$(document).mousedown(function(e){
 if( e.button == 2 ) { 
 $('a').css("color","red"); 
 return false; 
 } 
 return true; 
 });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/8RwsK/)

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "a",
    function (e) {
        if (e.button == 2) {
            $(this).css("color", "red");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: That's perfect. I tried to use a hex color code value instead of a word value, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried `$(this).css("color", "#416b99");`, but its not taking.

Comment: @Matt It is working but the difference isn't that big, maybe you're just not noticing it. http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/8RwsK/1/

Comment: Having an issue with this function in IE8 on some links, as well as Firefox. Is there a way to target specific div classes, instead of all anchor links?

Comment: @Matt Yes. `a.className`

Comment: @Matt No, this would work even on IE5.5. You're probably doing something wrong. Show us your full code

Comment: `$(document).on("mousedown", "a.matching",
        function (e) {
            if (e.button == 2) {
                $(this).css("color", "purple");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });`

Comment: I meant including the DOM etc. Prepare a jsfiddle with the exact problem and I'll check it on IE8

Comment: Works on my IE10's IE 8 Mode.